# Store large files for offline access in web application

Tags: html, web-applications, architecture, offline-browsing, app-offline.htm

I have a requirement where the web application needs to store about *2 GB* of files of various formats `.htm, .pptx,.docx, etc.` for offline access.

What is the best approach to implement this requirement in HTML5 ?

Comment: What and who is the site for? Why do you consider storing such large amounts of data in every user's browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sites (like html pages, images, resources, etc.) offline available just create a manifest file and declare your server-delivered files to be locally cached. If you'd like to storage data for these sites offline use localStorage therefore.

But I assume that 2 GB is way to big -- most browsers are configured to take something about 5 MB. If the website is for internal use only you may change browser preferences therefore; but for public websites this may be a major issue.